# Java library to create PDF documents with Acroforms (Free + gratis)

Tags: gratis, open-source, pdf, documentation-generator

I am looking for a library which, like Apache FOP, enables you to start from a template document (which has the contents in XML, similar to HTML), and apply styling to it, to create a PDF. I have been very happily using Apache FOP for this so far, but the issue I have with it is that I am unable to create any fillable acroforms in it, without writing an extension.

Are there any alternatives to it (Free and gratis) which offer similar capabilities, but also offer acroforms?

So, to sum up the requirements

- Has to be able to convert an (xml) template/content to a PDF
- Has to be able to add fillable acroforms
- Users have to be able to fill in acroforms and save the PDF
- Definitely stable library, if open source
- Easily importable via maven
- Very, very, very preferably gratis and free

Comment: So, why the downvote?

Comment: Check the PDFBox. It supports AcroForms. But not sure about the 1st feature.